# How do you show System.out and System.err in a UML Sequence Diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I'm drawing a UML Sequence Diagram for a `writeToFile()` method. In the method, the following calls are made:

- System.out.println()
- System.err.println()
- System.exit();

I'm confused about how to represent this in the diagram. Do I draw three seperate rectangles: System.out, System.err and System respectively?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use three lifelines:

1. System.out
2. System.err
3. System

And then show the three calls

1. println (message to System.out instance)
2. println (message to System.err instance)
3. exit (message to System instance)

Comment: That's what I went with. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> Do I draw three seperate rectangles: System.out, System.err and System respectively?

That's a pragmatic and perfectly valid way to do it.  Each is an "object" of sorts, so fine to show that way.

An alternative would be to show a single object lifeline for "System".  Might reduce clutter if (a) you have a number of other objects and (b) highlighting which of out/err/exit isn't really that important in what you're trying to show.

Really comes down to what you're trying to communicate.

hth.